# Triggering Hammer.js drag/slide behavior on mouse click

Tags: javascript, horizontal-scrolling, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js to allow for dragging between panes. I also want to allow an alternate action where there's also a "Next" button you can click on (with a mouse) or touch (on touchscreen), that will automatically animate a slide to the next screen.

Imagine the [Hammer.js Carousel demo](http://rawgit.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/1.1.3/tests/manual/carousel.html) with a "next" button in the middle of the page. When you click, it acts as if you did a slideleft to take you to the next pane.

I figured I should be able to trigger with something like:

```
var hammertime = Hammer('button.next-button').on("tap", function(event) {
    self.next();        
});
```

That only seems to put my mouse into drag mode, rather than executing the whole animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. self.next() will evidently not work as the next function is not defined in the self element.

You need to initizalize a new carousel instance, and then call the showPane(index) method:

> ```
>       var hammertime = Hammer(doubletapRegion).on("tap", function (event) {
>           console.log(event);
>           var carousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
>           carousel.init();
>           carousel.showPane(1);
>       });
> ```

This code will move the the second pane (index = 1). You can of course put a variable there.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I needed. I'm calling it on `$('button.next-button').click(function(){` then getting the current pane from a data attribute on the link, then passing that to `showPane`.