# Hammer.js - carousel next and previous button

Tags: javascript

I'm creating something similar to the hammer.js carousel. I'd like to add next and previous buttons to the carousel. I found this solution on StackOverflow: [Triggering Hammer.js drag/slide behavior on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582578/triggering-hammer-js-drag-slide-behavior-on-mouse-click).

Using the code from the above link I was able to get the next button working, but the previous button with the same code doesn't work.

Code for the next button:

```
var nexthammertime = Hammer('.next').on("tap", function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      var nextCarousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
      nextCarousel.init();
      nextCarousel.showPane(1);
  });
```

Code for the previous button:

```
var previoushammertime = Hammer('.previous').on("tap", function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      var previousCarousel= new Carousel("#carousel");
      previousCarousel.init();
      previousCarousel.showPane(0);
  });
```

Comment: single comma missing after previous

Comment: Thanks @DmitryKvochkin. I somehow missed that when copying it over. I've edited the post and also changed previousCarousel.showPane(1) to previousCarousel.showPane(0), that was a mistake as well.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work so I tried `previousCarousel.showPane(current_pane-1);` and that works as long as I click twice. How do I get it to work on the first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

Code for the next button:

```
var nexthammertime = Hammer('.next').on("tap", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  var nextCarousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
  nextCarousel.init();
  nextCarousel.showPane(1);
});
```

Code for the previous button:

```
var previoushammertime = Hammer('.previous').on("tap", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  var previousCarousel= new Carousel("#carousel");
  previousCarousel.init();
});
```